# Doing if- then- next in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns that I am searching for text in. If the text appears in any one column I want to add a row and do some additional configuration.

However, if it appears more than once in a row I want it to stop and move to next row.

Logic Being: check row one column at a time, if ABC appears, insert row set counter=1 if counter =1 skip to next row.

```
For x = 1 To 1000
  Count = 0
  For y = 1 To 19
    If Count = 1 Then Next x
    End If
    If Left(cell(x, y), 8) = "ABC" Then
      Rows(x+1).Insert
      Count = 1
    End If
  Next y
Next x
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim Count As Integer

'Loop the rows
For x = 1 To 1000
    Count = 0
    'Check the columns
    For y = 1 To 19
        If Left(ws.Cells(x, y), 3) = "ABC" Then
            'Increment the counter if we found it
            Count = Count + 1
            'This will prevent looping all the columns once we have more than one occurrence.  This will help performance. 
            If Count > 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next y
    'After checking all the columns, add a row if we found the text only one time
    If Count = 1 Then
        ws.Rows(x+1).Insert
        'Do other stuff here
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: @Bill Flippen I also changed your Left( , 8) to Left( , 3) since your example is looking for "ABC"

Comment: sorry about the left(,8) am actually looking for something other than ABC. thanks for the answer will check it out.

Comment: I added the variable declarations and changes the cell() to ws.Cells() while making sure it worked when i got back to my computer.

Comment: @MatthewD you probably want to adjust the Insert line to `ws.Rows(x+1).Insert` also

Comment: @joehanna I think you are correct even though it works as is.

Comment: @MatthewD it is just for safety and consistency in case the worksheet in question is not `Active` when this code is executed.

Comment: Thanks for all the fine tuning, this was mainly for a one time use, so I didn't cross the i's and dot the t's.  The main issue that was answered was using the `exit for` command, I will tuck that away for definite future use

Comment: @Bill Flippen  - Glad to help.